# can animals override instinct?

Tags: altruism

I would say that one of features that separates human consciousness from animal is the ability override instinctive behavior. A human infant will jerk its hand away from a hot surface. An older child you can communicate with at the basic level may not although experimenting with this is no doubt unethical. An adult can consciously overcome this instinct.

Are there experiments testing this idea with animals? In animals that science claims are self-aware, it would be interesting to know if they can overcome the automatic reaction to negative instincts.
The first step would possibly be to see if one negative instinct can be overcome in the presence of another. Like will a really hungry chimp walk across a painfully hot surface to reach food? This seems likely but I am unaware of any such testing.

A more interesting example will would be cases of real animal altruism. Science is quick to tout what some call animal altruism as hardcoded and evolving genetically e.g. lions defending prides, mothers defending young. And I agree this can be hardcoded and genetic since I am not aware of lions NOT defending prides or mothers leaving young to predators.

However, these links show cases of what some may call true animal altruism.
 Dogs braving the danger of the highway to help other animals.
https://www.quora.com/Are-animals-capable-of-selflessness-Do-they-have-the-desire-to-help-others

Leopardess adopts baby baboon
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9DOxH5RyWQ

Comment: The trouble is our motives don't have labels on them, "instinct", "altruism" etc. Different parts of the brain produce different responses to the same stimuli and it is then the job of the cerebral cortex to calculate which of the competing options to follow, some of these responses are "hard-wired" others not, but there is no single "instinct" which our conciousness, or that of other animals can, "overcome", just a range of competing options **almost all** of which are processed by the cerebral cortex in every creature that has one.

Comment: How do I move a question? Just repost?

Comment: @Isaacson You can hold your hand to a hot surface if you wanted. And the videos are indications of animals overcoming instincts. So its very likely consciousness can overcome hardwiring.

Comment: @AnoopAlex This is a common misconception that causes few problems in animal studies, but massive problems in human ethics. There is no evidence whatsoever that they are "overcoming instincts", there are just a range of potential responses to the various stimuli in the scenario and the animals are choosing one of them using either learned or novel patterns in the cortex. There is no way of distinguishing "hard-wiring" from "conciousness" in *these types* of actions, **all** of them go through the cerebral cortex to be decided on.

Comment: Ever housetrain a puppy?  Or consider that a horse's instincts are to flee from perceived dangers, including four-legged wolflike predators, yet with training you can ride your horse around all sorts of scary things, and take your dogs along :-)

Comment: @jamesqf: I realize animals can learn percieved dangers are not actual dangers but I was thinking more along the lines of when the threat is real. When a puppy or horse learns the people he sees wont harm him, he no longer fears. But the example I gave of burning hot surface to reach food presents a real threat. I realize there are ethical issues here so am also curious if there have been examples observed in nature.

Comment: you may want to look at the vast number of studies done on rats with electric shocks, you would be amazed what behavioral alterations are possible. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03209595.pdf the branch or science you are looking for is called ethology.

Comment: What makes you think that altruism isn't instinctual? Certainly certain forms of it are, parents caring for their offspring for example. The examples you mention may be examples of an instinctual behavior applied to a non-typical subject.

Answer (score 1):

**Instinct and learning drive *almost* all behavior in the animal kindgom**. We are only considering animals with nervous systems in this discussion, but [non-neural learning](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep38427) has been documented.

All animals have instinct. Instincts manifest themselves as desires that elicit "automatic" behaviors. A good demonstration of instinct is to skip a meal and then put yourself in the presence of your favorite snack. You don't have to think "I would like to eat now" before reaching for the bag, it happens "automatically". That is one of many instincts found in *Homo Sapiens*.

Instincts are encoded genetically and in terms of speciation, population size and generation times insects are *more* evolved than vertebrates. We would expect them to have instincts just as complex (if not more so) than mammals despite their far simpler brains.

Learning is found in many species, including in [jellyfish](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20540961/), [earthworms](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3912444/), [snails](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2743145/), [and many insects](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26263427/#:%7E:text=Insects%20possess%20small%20brains%20but,framework%20of%20simple%20associative%20learning.). The *desire* to learn in my opinion is largely instinctual as can be seen by the enthusiasm of a young child. **If learning is instinctual, is learning to override instinct actually overriding instinct?**

The very smartest animal species can occasionally exhibit "creativity" which goes beyond instinct and learning and can in fact fight against instinct. For example, Orcas [beach hunt sea lions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKTIMvQwoLQ&ab_channel=DrIngridN.Visser) which requires overcoming their powerful instinct not to beach. The calves learn this from the mothers (often by doing "dry runs" with no prey within reach), **but *someone* had to come up with this idea in the first place**. Whoever that Orca was had to fight their own instinct *without* resorting to learned behavior.

Humans only have [half](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animals_by_number_of_neurons) the *cortical* neuron count of Orcas but are still above most Cetaceans and are the top non-Cetacean at over twice Chimpanzees and Elephants. Even at such a "lofty" spot in the animal kingdom, truly creative behavior is rare. But imitation [is so good](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25545051/) that these rare innovations spread around the world and became fixed in collective memory. Eventually, the accumulation of all these inventions led to modern technology (opposable thumbs also helped). There was only one Bitcoin but there are now >12,000 copycats.

Even though no animal species (human or otherwise) commonly breaks out of both instinctual and learnt behaviors, it happens in the smartest species occasionally and can have a big effect given enough time.